# Can't reference DataTable Column when it is created by a query with "AS"

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I have created a DataTable that I fill using a SQL query that has an 'AS' in it.

Example:

```
SELECT (tblUser.FirstName + ' ' + tblUser.LastName) AS 'UserFullName' 
FROM tblUser
```

I use

```
SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dtblUserInfo)
```

to fill the table and have verified that the column UserFullName exists with a string of data inside.

I try and reference this cell with

```
string strUserFullName = dtblUserInfo.Rows[0]["UserFullName"].ToString();
```

and even though I can see that there is data in that cell by adding a watch, it returns an empty string.

I am sure that Row[0] is the row that has the cell with data in it and would not normally hard code this value but is just for explaination and debug purposes.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks,
    Steve.

Comment: If you watch the datatable, do you see the column 'UserFullName'?

Comment: Did you try removing the single quotes around the `UserFullName`?

Comment: Upon closer inspection of the column names I see that there was actually another column named UserFullName included in the results set (from a SELECT tblName.*). As such, the table was appending a 1 to my created column (UserFullName1) to compensate. Basically, I am retarded and thank you to all who tried to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace this

```
SELECT (tblUser.FirstName + ' ' + tblUser.LastName) AS 'UserFullName' 
FROM tblUser
```

by this

```
SELECT (tblUser.FirstName + ' ' + tblUser.LastName) AS UserFullName 
FROM tblUser
```

When you are using `AS` you don't need the single quotes it's expecting a new column name. Column names are never within quotes.

If you want to replace the name with 2 words like User Full Name, you need use [], for example [UserFullName].

Comment: I am pretty sure you have to have quotes when the new column name as a space in it. Not that anyone should ever do that but I think I just needlessly adopted the practice.

Comment: Even though the issue was my stupididty I marked this as the answer because I feel like if this case happened to others, this would probably be a good solution to try.

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't receiving an exception when accessing the cell, that tells you that the AS column description is not the problem.

In addition, because the code isn't throwing an exception when you access row 0, this tells you that your retrieval of data is working correctly.

This means that the problem is actually in your data.

To verify this, just execute the SQL script directly against the database. If you have NULLs in your results, this could be part of the problem (although in SQL Server, that should result in a null column value).

Comment: This is also a good answer. More or less because it has a good set of steps to go through to find the root cause of issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this codes for see content of your DataTable:
It will help you find the mistake.

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dtblUserInfo.Rows)
{
    foreach (var item in dr.ItemArray)
    {
        r += item.ToString();
    }
    r += "\r\n";
}
MessageBox.Show(r);
```

Then verify your query...

Answer (score 0):

PhaDaPhunk said:

> Just replace this
>
> ```
> SELECT (tblUser.FirstName + ' ' + tblUser.LastName) AS 'UserFullName' FROM tblUser
> ```
>
> by this
>
> ```
> SELECT (tblUser.FirstName + ' ' + tblUser.LastName) AS UserFullName FROM tblUser
> ```
>
> When you are using AS you don't need the single quotes it's expecting
>   a new column name. Column names are never within quotes.

and this is good answer, and I have small additional tip.
If you want to replace the name with 2 words like "User Full Name", you need use [], for example [User Full Name].